# Using iptables to block connections from local network

Tags: linux, networking, security, iptables, firewall

My network's **DHCP address range** goes from **192.168.0.100 to 192.168.0.199** and it's **subnet mask** is **255.255.255.0**.

I want to use iptables to DROP any INPUT (and OUTPUT too, if possible, as I don't want any type of connection with other devices in my network) from this IP range, blocking then all the incoming connections coming from (and outgoing to) my local network.

I think I know how to do this, but I still have some pending stuff to learn...

like, I've seen people saying to set the rule `iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.0.100/24 -j DROP`, but I don't know if it's right for my network, since I don't know what this "/24" stands for in this rule, and I've seen people using "`/16`" ou "`/32`" in other cases, so I feel a little confused about it all.

In some answers and threads, I have also seen people saying about the rule: 
`iptables -A INPUT -m iprange --src-range 192.168.0.100-192.168.0.199 -j DROP`, but these threads are old and I don't know if it is the best option for blocking what I am asking about.

So, since I feel confused, I am asking here for some networking/iptables/Linux more advanced mind who can explain me this better and tell me what rule should I use to do this.

**EDIT #1:**

I currently already `iptables -P DROP` the **INPUT**, **OUTPUT** and **FORWARD** chains, and have the two following rules:

```
iptables -I INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

iptables -I OUTPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED,NEW -j ACCEPT
```

regarding this last one, should I change "**-m state --state**" to "**-m conntrack --ctstate**" or are both the same thing?

Comment: You should use `-m conntrack` because `-m state` is deprecated. They are functionally equivalent.

Comment: so, isn't `-m iprange --src-range 192.168.0.100-192.168.0.199` deprecated too in relation to, for example, `-s 192.168.0.100/24`?

Comment: 192.168.0.100/24 (it should be 192.168.0.0/24) is not the same as the range 100-199 because 192.168.0.0/24 containes addresses 0-255 ( minus reserved for broadcast and network (but not true for point-to-point - not your case) ) And according to [man-page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables) iprange is not deprecated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> since I don't know what this "/24" stands for in this rule, and I've seen people using "/16" ou "/32" in other cases, so I feel a little confused about it all.

It is the size of the network in slash notation `/24 = 255.255.255.0` in "netmask" notation. (It specifies how large a subnet can be - machines in the subnet will have the same prefix of IP addresses)

What you want to achieve (if I understood correctly) is to block incoming traffic from other devices that gain their IP address from the DHCP server.

```
 iptables -A INPUT -m iprange --src-range 192.168.0.100-192.168.0.199 -j DROP
```

`-A` means append so make sure you are not allowing the connection that should be dropped before this rule (or specify `-I INPUT <number_of_desired_position>` as "insert" )

`-m`stands for "match" - which module you wish to use (because you wish to use an ip range a special module is loaded and it "matches" the addresses for you - in the same manner you can create a stateful firewall)

now you permit any other connection (if you have a permissive policy you are fine to skip)

```
iptables -A INPUT -j ACCEPT
```

Now outgoing traffic, because you are dropping the incomming connections you will not be able to establish a connection to any other machine in the range, but your packets will still be able to try to connect (your machine could try to start connection but would never be able to establish it because of no answer from remote machine - that is true for TCP at least)

So you should be fine leaving it accepted.

But if you wish to have ability to connect to other machines in the subnet (e.g. connect to an http server in the specified range) you can do that by adding  the:

```
iptables -I INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

the `--state ESTABLISHED` is there for enabling a stateful connections (those which you tried to iniciate)

Comment: so, with all the chains -P DROP'd, which rule should I add firstly in their rulesets to things to work properly? 

should I `-I INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT` and `-A INPUT -m iprange --src-range 192.168.0.100-192.168.0.199 -j DROP`

or `-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT` and `-I INPUT -m iprange --src-range 192.168.0.100-192.168.0.199 -j DROP`?

Comment: If you have flushed your iptables (contiaining no rules) You can go with `-A INPUT -m conntrack --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT;  -A INPUT -m iprange ...` or to first one of the two you mentioned (append is always append at the end - in current state - in the same manner insert without number is insert at the beginning

Comment: so I should append (-A) both of the rules? even when I want one of them upper in the ruleset?

Comment: Ok - look you have no rule in list. [''] <- this is your list, you append one at the end, let say it is rule 'A'. ['A'] <- this is your list now. Now again we will append a rule, but now it will be rule B. ['A','B'] <- is your list now, (note the first rule is on the left). You append to the end, but that does not mean it will stand at the end forever.

Comment: So adding with -A work like a 'arrival order', when the ones that were added first stay in the top of the 'list'?

and -I is like a 'cheat' to jump the line and stay in the first or another wanted position?

Comment: so, with every chain **-P DROP'd** and flushed, with no rules, setting only the following two rules is enough to drop unintended connections coming from my own local network?
`-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT` and
`-A OUTPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED,NEW -j ACCEPT`,

no need to go and drop specifically my network's IP range?

Comment: `-A OUTPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED,NEW -j ACCEPT ` you can basically can have` -P OUTPUT ACCEPT` - you will enable any outgoing traffic (originating from you) and incoming only the one you established - (you can still communicate with others if you iniciate that)

Comment: Yes, I got it, this is my last doubt in this thread, I swear: but saying that I want to add both `-m conntrack` and `-m iprange` rules, what ones should I add before/firstly in the ruleset? the `-m iprange` ones or the `-m conntrack` ones?

Comment: Depends on their semantics, usually you wish to enable established connections and therefore you put -m conntrack related/established etc. as your first rule to shorten the lookup time (rules are processed sequentially) because this rule matches really large portion of network traffic

Comment: no problem, I hope that now it is at least a tiny bit easier to imagine. Have a nice time using iptables :-).